# Wiremock UI to connect to locally running Wiremock standalone server

Tags: user-interface, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have downloaded the wiremock standalone jar locally. And I am starting the standalone server using below command. 
*java -jar wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.26.3.jar --port 8089 &*
I am placing all the mocked endpoints under the mappings folder.

I need a user interface which can connect to my wiremock server and show me all the mappings. 
It would be of advantage if the UI could provide features for editing, deleting and adding new files permanently.

Comment: I was also looking for it. Did you get a chance to try out this ui client - https://hub.docker.com/r/holomekc/wiremock-gui?

Answer (score 2):

Use any version from https://github.com/holomekc/wiremock/releases and run executable jar having mocked endpoint JSONs under the mappings folder.If you have not provided port configuration then UI with mapping details will be accessible over URL http://localhost:8080/__admin/webapp

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://github.com/plouc/wiremock-ui and its [live demo](https://plouc.github.io/wiremock-ui/).